# Validating required fields and confirming fields in c# visual studio

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having trouble with creating a form that requires the user to enter information in the fields, Confirm an email and password entry, and go onto the next form when all those fields are matched/filled in. Individually, the code I have works, but I cannot seem to find a way to make it so that all the requirements are met before going onto the next form.  At the moment it just goes onto the next form if i click the continue button.

some excerpts of the code i have are:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
{
    lblRequirementsError.Text = ("All required fields have not been filled.");
}

if (txtBoxEmail.Text != txtBoxConfirmEmail.Text)
{
    lblEmailError.Text = ("Email reentry does not match. Please reenter.");
}

if (txtBoxPassword.Text != txtBoxConfirmPassword.Text)
{
    lblPasswordError.Text = ("Password reentry does not match. Please reenter.");
}

this.Hide();
frmBilling secondForm = new frmBilling();
secondForm.Show();
```

Comment: Is this Windows Forms? Web Forms? MVC?

Comment: I apologize for not making that clear in the question. It is in a Windows Form Application.

Comment: Google "windows forms field validation", and the first hit is [User Input Validation in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the form is created and opened regardless of the if results, because the code for it is outside the ifs. First, check that no fields are empty, and then, check that the validation has been met, THEN open the new window. Something like this should work:

```
//If both email and password are not empty
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
{
    //if both email and password math the re entry
    if (txtBoxEmail.Text == txtBoxConfirmEmail.Text &&
        txtBoxPassword.Text == txtBoxConfirmPassword.Text)
    {
        //execute the code to open the new form
        this.Hide();
        frmBilling secondForm = new frmBilling();
        secondForm.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (! txtBoxEmail.Text.Equals( txtBoxConfirmEmail.Text))
{
    lblEmailError.Text = ("Email reentry does not match. Please reenter.");
}

if (! txtBoxPassword.Text.Equals( txtBoxConfirmPassword.Text))
{
    lblPasswordError.Text = ("Password reentry does not match. Please reenter.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are you using web applications forms in visual studio 2012. You can use field validators inside the .ASPX file for any field that you want to validate before form submission. This is much easier that writing everything in C#.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Although I do wish I could use the field validator, I have to write the code as I am doing it for a project.  Would this particular example require a looping statement? When I add the code for opening the new form, it seems to disregard the conditional statements.

Comment: try removing this.hide and use something like redirect(JSP style). I am sure there is redirect in ASP as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DataAnnotation if you are binding or converting your controls to the data objects. Then it will be easy to validate. Please see the link for more details

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590(VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bool validationStatus = default(bool);

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
{
    lblRequirementsError.Text = ("All required fields have not been filled.");
    validationStatus  = true;
}

if (txtBoxEmail.Text != txtBoxConfirmEmail.Text)
{
    lblEmailError.Text = ("Email reentry does not match. Please reenter.");
    validationStatus  = true;
}

if (txtBoxPassword.Text != txtBoxConfirmPassword.Text)
{
    lblPasswordError.Text = ("Password reentry does not match. Please reenter.");
    validationStatus  = true;
}

if(!validationStatus)
{
   Hide();
   frmBilling secondForm = new frmBilling();
   secondForm.Show();
}
```